# how to form submit show modal popup with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created two dropdown field and i create when all the fields filled the submit button going to enable and after, i click submit popup will open... this is want my actual output.

but now here, its not working.. can you help me please? i hope my question is understandable.

**[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/vujpnfrz/)**

```js
jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);

var toValidate = "#frm_acc,#to_acc,#accloading";
valid = false;
$(toValidate).change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
  }
  $(toValidate).each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
      valid = true;
      $("#accMergebtn").click(function() { // click function to show popup
        $('#accloading').modal('show');
      });
    } else {
      valid = false;
    }
  });

  if (valid === true) {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.2/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post" id="contactForm">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- From Account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="frm_acc">FROM:*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="frm_account" id="frm_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- To account name -->
    <div class="form-group col-6" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
      <label class="col-sm-6 control-label p-sm-0 acc-merge" for="to_acc">TO*</label>
      <select class="form-control select-data .has-success" name="to_account" id="to_acc" required>
        <option value="">Choose an items</option>
        <option value="1">Plumz</option>
        <option value="2">Plumz2</option>
        <option value="3">Plumz3</option>
        <option value="4">Plumz4</option>
        <option value="5">Plumz5</option>
      </select>
      <div class="input-group col-sm-6 p-sm-0 form-group"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Submit Button -->

  <div class="form-group ml-auto mt-2 mb-0">
    <div class="col-md-12 stockform_submit" id="">
      <button type="submit" class="btn add-btn submit-btn" id="accMergebtn">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default reset-btn stock_rst" style="left: 0%" id="reset-btn">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- progress bar -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="accloading" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal_load">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="./img/loading.gif" alt="Please Wait" class="load_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

> Im using all latest versions bootstrap, jQuery,...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if both the dropdown is havinf some value or not for disable false...
Change your script to this...

```
jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);

var toValidate = "#frm_acc,#to_acc,#accloading";
valid = false;
$(toValidate).change(function() {
  if (jQuery(this).val().length > 0) {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', true);
  } else {
    jQuery(this).data('valid', false);
  }
  $(toValidate).each(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).data('valid') == true) {
      valid = true;
      $("#accMergebtn").click(function() { // click function to show popup
        $('#accloading').modal('show');
      });
    } else {
      valid = false;
    }

    if($('#frm_acc').val() && $('#to_acc').val()){
        jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', false);
    } else{
        jQuery("#accMergebtn").prop('disabled', true);
    }

});

});
```

This will work!

Add this for the pop up  problem

```
$('#contactForm').on('submit', function(){
    $('#accloading').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: sir, but the modal popup is not working. that only the problem sir..